# Determine if any audio files are corrupted in a folder

Tags: windows, audio, ogg

I am attempting to run an application (the game, Call of Cthulu: Dark Corners Of The Earth), but at a specific part, there is always a crash. From my testing, I've determined with some degree of certainty that the crash is caused by an audio file that plays at this particular part. Now, admittedly, there are a variety of possible causes of the crash (driver issues, codec issues or corrupt file, AFAIK, or something completely different), but assuming I wanted to determine if it's a corrupt file, is there any way to do it?

The files are all .ogg files.

Basically, I'm looking for a utility or instructions to recurse through a file tree, testing all the files for corruption or misformatting. I would prefer it not PLAY each file (there are a few thousand, would probably take a while), just sanity check them.

Thanks all!

**EDIT**

Just a little more info. I could maybe tell the audio file by its first few moments of playing, but as I say, there are a few thousand files to go through, many sounding similar. Also, interestingly, the audio always plays partway through, then dies at a specific spot.

One option I was exploring was to do a checksum on the whole folder tree, and compare it with another copy of the game (probably torrented, should be legal, as I own a copy already).

Comment: Just a word of warning, I'd be careful with torrents. While they are legal if you already own a copy (I'm no expert on this, so feel free to prove me wrong) they may contain viruses. So be careful.

Comment: Why don't you re-install or repair the game?

Comment: @harrymc I've tried that a few times. No dice. I was wondering if my install source was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any OGG validators, but you may want to try an audio conversion program.  Convert the OGG to MP3 (or anything else).  You should be able to queue up the files and if an OGG file is invalid hopefully conversion program may choke on it and alert you.

If you know someone else with the program you could use a program like [hashdeep](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/) to generate the hashes for the OGG files (of the whole game) and use hashdeep in audit mode to check the known good hashes to your files.  (A torrent file could do the same, if who created it didn't ZIP/RAR the files.  If they didn't, you may be able to use the torrent file to validate your files.)  I assume this is necessary because you don't have the CD (like the game is a downloaded game, as I'm not familiar with your game.)  If you did have the CD, then there are many program to compare files on a bit-by-bit level (I like [TreeComp](http://www.xs4all.nl/~lploeger/TreeComp3.htm).)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [Xiph mailing list message from 2003](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/vorbis/2003-April/022972.html),

> `ogginfo` should check most things, at least the CRC integrity of
>   everything.

I don't know whether ogginfo is available for Windows though. You'd also have to script the recursion part, as ogginfo doesn't do that (at least on UNIX).